# How to set the variant image in Woocommerce 'alt' the same as its name?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem. I want to assign an `alt` for each photo in the woocommerce such as the name of the variant. How can I do this?

I found this: [How to automatically apply woocommerce product title to all product images alt tags?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258007/how-to-automatically-apply-woocommerce-product-title-to-all-product-images-alt-t)

but, how can I have titles to have the name of the variant?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
In file variable.php after "do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' )" paste this code:

```
$post_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post(get_the_ID()));
$title = get_post_field( 'post_title', get_post(get_the_ID()));

if($available_variations) {
for ($i = 0; $i < count($available_variations); $i++) {
    $value = $available_variations[$i];
    $arrayWithAttribute = $value["attributes"];
    $image = $value["image"];

    $stringNameAttribute = http_build_query($arrayWithAttribute,'','-');
    $alt = $post_slug.'-'.str_replace("=","-",str_replace("attribute_pa_","",$stringNameAttribute));

    $titleimg = str_replace("-"," ", $title.' '.str_replace("="," ",str_replace("attribute_pa_","",$stringNameAttribute)));

    $available_variations[$i]['image']['alt']=$alt;
    $available_variations[$i]['image']['title']= $titleimg;
}
}
```

And paste in function.php:

```
function wc_get_gallery_image_html_change( $attachment_id, $main_image = false ) {
        $parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $attachment_id);
        $post_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post(get_the_ID($parent)) );
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID($parent) );
        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        $actualImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $full_size );
        $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $parent);

        $alt = '';
        $titleimg = '';
        if($available_variations) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($available_variations); $i++) {
            $value = $available_variations[$i];
            $arrayWithAttribute = $value["attributes"];
            $image = $value["image"];


            if($image['url'] === $actualImage[0]) {

            $stringNameAttribute = http_build_query($arrayWithAttribute,'','-');
            $alt = $post_slug.'-'.str_replace("=","-",str_replace("attribute_pa_","",$stringNameAttribute));

            $titleimg = str_replace("-"," ", $title.' '.str_replace("="," ",str_replace("attribute_pa_","",$stringNameAttribute)));

            $available_variations[$i]['image']['alt']=$alt;

            $available_variations[$i]['image']['title']= $titleimg;
            }
        }
    }


        $flexslider        = (bool) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', get_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' ) );
        $gallery_thumbnail = wc_get_image_size( 'gallery_thumbnail' );
        $thumbnail_size    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', array( $gallery_thumbnail['width'], $gallery_thumbnail['height'] ) );
        $image_size        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_image_size', $flexslider || $main_image ? 'woocommerce_single' : $thumbnail_size );
        $full_size         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'full' ) );
        $thumbnail_src     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $thumbnail_size );
        $full_src          = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $full_size );
        $alt_text          = trim( wp_strip_all_tags( get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ) ) );

        $image             = wp_get_attachment_image(
            $attachment_id,
            $image_size,
            false,
            apply_filters(
                'woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params',
                array(
                    'title'                   => $titleimg ? $titleimg : _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_title', $attachment_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
                    'data-caption'            => _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $attachment_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
                    'data-src'                => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
                    'data-large_image'        => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
                    'data-large_image_width'  => esc_attr( $full_src[1] ),
                    'data-large_image_height' => esc_attr( $full_src[2] ),
                    'class'                   => esc_attr( $main_image ? 'wp-post-image' : '' ),
                    'alt'                     => $alt,
                ),
                $attachment_id,
                $image_size,
                $main_image
            )
        );
        return '<div data-thumb="' . esc_url( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"  class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="' . esc_url( $full_src[0] ) . '">' . $image . '</a></div>';
    }
```

next edit product-image.php and change line 42 to:

```
$html  = wc_get_gallery_image_html_change( $post_thumbnail_id, true );
```